# Reorganizing data in Access Table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following table setup. [image]

I am trying to reorganize it so that it is set up as follows:

ITEMID----TITLE1----FILENAME1----TITLE2----FILENAME2----etc...

so that there is one row per ITEMID

Is there an easy way to automate this either through SQL or Access settings? I checked out crosstabs, but that does not appear to be what I am looking for, and I do not know enough about access to even formulate an articulate google query. If anyone could just point me in the right direction I would appreciate it greatly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Guessing that you don't want to get into embedded while loops and reading/writing recordsets, then crosstab is the way to go.

But first you should set up the data with one helper column that does a running count of your ItemID, restarting at 1 each time you find a new ItemID.   You will then use this field in your crosstab.

Or just do it all in Excel.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Any suggestions as to how to create said helper column?

Comment: If you were in Excel, it would be an if statement comparing the current record with the previous, and if it changes then you start your count from 1.  i.e.  x = current row, y = previous row, h = the previous helper cell;  therefore if(x=y, h+1, 1).   If you're in Access then you'd use the same logic but do it by going through the recordset.